# How can I write a Python script to generate an Excel file from SQL code?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is run a python script to generate an excel file from the given sql code:

[image: sql script]

Comment: Do you mean from the SQL statement shown (why, how?) or the resulting query data? Where's your code?

Comment: from the resulting query data that the SQL statement shown makes, I want that to become an excel file. do you know what modules to use? I am lost

Answer (score 1):

<s>I don't know if there is a library made to write excel file but</s> you can use CSV file and them import into excel
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples

Just a google search :

- https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt
- https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter